# Connecting SharePoint Designer to SharePoint Online Site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

**Background:** 
Im migrating a SP solution from sp 2013 onprem->SP online.
Ihave a custom Workflow, once made in SP Designer.

**Problem:**
I am trying to connect SP Designer to a SP Online but I only get the error message

> We are unable to connect right now. Please check your network and try
>   again later
>    And then
>
> Access Denied. Before opening files in this location, you must first
>   add the web site to your trusted sites list, browse to the web site,
>   and select the option to login automatically.

I have gone to IE->Options->security tab and added my site as a secure site. I dont know what they mean by the "select to option to login automatically".

Comment: refer this link - https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/connect-sharepoint-online-using-designer-2013-sandeep-mishra

Comment: You can refer this link also - https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/179550/unable-to-connect-site-from-sharepoint-designer-2013?rq=1

Comment: No, none of these was what I was looking for, maybe my problem was to simple, that not many others have had it. Ill keep your links at the back of my mind though, for later problems. :)

Answer (score 1):

The "login automatically" is a reference to the "keep me signed in" checkbox on the username/password page when you log in. If you've already logged in, log out, and then check that box when you log back in.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. Im using many different accounts so I didnt want it to remember any of them and Id forgot about/suppressed that option. But your absolutely right. It works now

Comment: ...Didnt work after all. I could go past the "login"-step and got to the item listing, but when I tried to open the site I got access denied. Now I dont get past the first step again...